# ASP.Net - Service Unavailable

Tags: asp.net

So im migrating my website to a new web server (win 2003 64bit)
Setup the website set the framework to 4.0, browse the site and get "Service Unavailable"
mmm, useful.
I notice that that the AppPool Crashes,
The event log reports "A process serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' reported a failure. The process id was '193312'.  The data field contains the error number."

Also I did have to follow this guide as my Asp.net was missing
2E002E002E00.aspx">http://weblogs.asp.net/plip/archive/2006/05/25/Where_2700_s-the-ASP.NET-Tab-in-IIS_3F00_-It_2700_s-Missing_2100_-I_2700_ve-installed-.NET-2.0-*2E002E002E00*.aspx

Any Ideas what I need to do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I am voting to migrate to sever fault

Comment: Does the user running the apppool has the correct permissions? (Belongs to group: IIS_WPG) Have you check the eventviewer for more details?

Comment: I've had similar problems to this before.  The cause ultimately was permissions.  In one obscure case the fault was that the uri namespace the application was trying to use, had been registered to a windows service I had created.  I agree with @Matt for now though, this should be moved to serverfault until an issue with the websites' code is identified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to uninstall IIS and framework, reinstall .net framework (64bit) by using aspnet_regiis -i

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your default app pool was set to .net 2.0.  Unlike 3.0 and 3.5, the 4.0 framework does not run on the 2.0 base.  You will need to set up the apppool to use .net 4.  If you are using IIS 7 you will be able to have 2 app pools using different frameworks.  However IIS 6 can only run 1 framework at a time.  So if you are running IIS 6 you will need to choose 2.0 or 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the application pool is set to 'Allow 32bit applications'=true.

you can check this by right clicking the application pool and choosing 'advanced settings'